# TypeError: documents must be a non-empty list

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm doing a program using Twitter API and MongoDB in 2.7 Python language.

I get a timeline and put it in a dictionary, which I want to store in a MongoDB database. To do this I have next code:

```
def saveOnBD(self, dic):
    client = MongoClient("xxxx", "port")
    db = client.DB_Tweets_User_Date
    collection = db.tweets
    collection.insert_many(dic)
```

I'm debbuging and `dic` it's not empty but I get next error:

```
TypeError: documents must be a non-empty list
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: what is  `print(dic)` output?

Comment: You say `dic` isn't empty, but is it a list?

Comment: all the info obtained by twitter api(user, tweet, date, ...), one of each tweet on user timeline. I create this dictionari like this: dict = {}. after I refill it with a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I trying many options, but i solved that question changing the post method.

Instead of:

```
collection.insert_many(dic)
```

I used this:

```
collection.insert_one(dic)
```

I supose that, as I try to post only a variable(dic) and "insert_many()" is for many variables that retun me the error. That change solved me the question

Comment: In my case i need to use the insert_many to perform a bulk operation. :(

Answer (score 1):

A list of documents must be passed to insert_many method

E.g.:

```
collection.insert_many([dic])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either put in an entry before running the bulk entry function or use insert()